# Parsing an RSS Feed in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, parsing, mongoid

So I'm new to Ruby on Rails, but I'm basically trying to parse through a feed using `SimpleRSS`, and then store various values and display it. I'm using MongoDB/the mongoid gem as the database.

I can parse through the feed, but then none of the values get correctly stored.

```
class FeedEntry

  include Mongoid::Document
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'simple-rss'
  require 'open-uri'

  field :name, type: String
  field :summary, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :published_at, type: DateTime
  field :guid, type: Integer

  def self.rssFeeder(feed_url)
    feed = SimpleRSS.parse open(feed_url)
    feed.items.each do |entry|
      unless FeedEntry.where(guid: entry.id).exists?
        FeedEntry.create!(
          name: entry.title,
          summary: entry.summary,
          url: entry.link,
          published_at: entry.pubDate,
          guid: entry.id
        ) 
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I can get that `FeedEntry.count` is 76, but all of the values stored are `nil`.

Does anyone see a clear error?

Comment: maybe only the guid is available/try emptying your table and running again.

Comment: On a side note, it might be better for performance and/or readability to grab a list of the feed IDs and query the database for them to see if the records exist, and if any of them do, filter out the Feed items before looping over them. ***Might***.

Comment: What do you get if you `puts entry.inspect` before creating your `FeedEntries`?

Comment: I can't really see the output of `puts entry.inspect` because of all the parsing garbage. Either way, nothing gets printed out that I can tell.
I can, however do `FeedEntry.first` and the `id` is a random 9-10 character garbage number, with all other values being `nil`.